# How to use Entity Framework with an Oracle database?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using VS 2022 and .NET 6.0.

I am trying to use Entity Framework Core for an Oracle database. I have used `Scaffold-DbContext` before but with a SQL Server database and no problems.

However, when I run `Scaffold-DbContext` for the Oracle database, I get an error:

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Connection request timed out

even though I can connect to it via Oracle SQL Developer with no problems.

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Context ComDBContext -Force "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<host>)(PORT=<port>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<servicename>)));User Id=<userid>;Password=<password>;load balancing=true;pooling=true;Min Pool Size=10;Connection Lifetime=120;Connection Timeout=60;" -Provider Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -Verbose -OutputDir Models
```

[image]

My project is a .NET 6.0 console app and have installed the following Nuget packages:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.3
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions  6.0.3
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers  6.0.3
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 6.0.3
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 6.0.3
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqIServer 6.0.3
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 6.0.3
- Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 6.21.61

I assume, I need to scaffold the database to create the `DbContext` and all the entity classes for Entity Framework Core.

Comment: You shouldn't post your full connection string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52280091/odp-net-core-scaffold-db-context